# Floating Button goes up with Bottom Sheet Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I don't understand why the `FloatingButton` is going up with the `BottomSheet`.

[image]

I tried to change the `sheetElevation` which is higher than the elevation of the `FloatingButton`, but the issue remains. That's because the code inside `BottomSheetScaffoldStack` says to move the `FloatingButton` up along with the `BottomSheet`. Is there any way to avoid that?

Here is the code of the `BottomSheetScaffold`:

```
BottomSheetScaffold(
  scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
  topBar = { TopBar(
    areButtonShowed = true,
    title = topBarTitle,
    onBackPressed = { BendRouter.navigateTo(onBackDestination) }
  ) },
  floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.Center,
  floatingActionButton = {
    ExtendedFloatingButton(
      text = context.getString(R.string.start),
      onClick = {}, // TODO
      modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(45.dp)
        .padding(
          start = 24.dp,
          end = 24.dp
        ),
      backgroundColor = PureWhite
    )
    
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(150.dp))
  },
  sheetBackgroundColor = PureWhite,
  sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp,
  sheetElevation = 70.dp,
  sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(50.dp),
  sheetContent = {
    openStretchDetails?.let { stretch ->
      BottomSheetView(stretch = stretch)
    }
  },
  content = { RoutinePageView(viewModel) }
)
```

And `ExtendedFloatingButton`:

```
@Composable
fun ExtendedFloatingButton(
  text: String,
  @DrawableRes icon: Int? = null,
  onClick: () -> Unit,
  modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
  elevation: Dp = 12.dp,
  backgroundColor: Color
) {
  ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
    text = {
      Text(
        text = text.uppercase(),
        color = Gray,
        fontSize = 18.sp,
        maxLines = 1,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
        letterSpacing = .5.sp
      )
    },
    onClick = onClick,
    icon = {
      icon?.let {
        Icon(
          painter = painterResource(id = it),
          contentDescription = ""
        )
      }
    },
    modifier = modifier,
    elevation = FloatingActionButtonDefaults.elevation(elevation),
    backgroundColor = backgroundColor
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `BottomSheetScaffold` has a default behavior that you can see by clicking on it while pressing CTRL. Looking at `BottomSheetScaffoldStack` inside the `BottomSheetScaffold.kt` class you'll see how the `FloatingButton` is moved along with the `BottomSheet`.

To solve this problem I used `ModalBottomSheetLayout` instead of `BottomSheetScaffold`.

```
ModalBottomSheetLayout(
  sheetState = bottomState,
  sheetContent = {
    Box(Modifier.defaultMinSize(minHeight = 1.dp)) {
      openStretchDetails?.let { stretch ->
        BottomSheetView(stretch = stretch)
        coroutineScope.launch {
          bottomState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)
        }
      }
    }
  },
  sheetBackgroundColor = PureWhite,
  sheetElevation = 16.dp,
  sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(50.dp),
) {
  Scaffold(
    topBar = { TopBar(
      areButtonShowed = true,
      title = topBarTitle,
      onBackPressed = { BendRouter.navigateTo(onBackDestination) }
    ) },
    floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.Center,
    floatingActionButton = {
      ExtendedFloatingButton(
        text = context.getString(R.string.start),
        onClick = {}, // TODO
        modifier = Modifier
          .fillMaxWidth()
          .height(45.dp)
          .padding(
            start = 24.dp,
            end = 24.dp
          ),
        backgroundColor = PureWhite
      )

      Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(150.dp))
    },
    content = { RoutinePageView(viewModel) }
  )
}
```

Add this on the top:

```
  val bottomState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
    confirmStateChange = { it != ModalBottomSheetValue.HalfExpanded }
  )
  val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
```